# PHP charset issue(it is different)

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, mbstring

I have an issue which is related to charset problem but it is different because I didn't have any Turkish character problem. However, if I want to it be upper, it will be problem.

**My Code is below**

```
//To Up title (Ş,I doesn't be upper)
$haberbaslik = strtoupper($haberbaslik);

//Explode title with space
$haberbaslik =  explode(" ",$haberbaslik);

for($i=0;$i<count($haberbaslik);$i++){
    // title which is exploded is in array
$list = str_split($haberbaslik[$i]);

for($j=0;$j<count($list);$j++){

    if($j==0){
        $text .= $list[$j];
        if($list[$j]=="'"){
                //It is problematic one. When it works, if char is Ş or I it give ? 
                $text .= mb_strtoupper($list[$j+1],'UTF-8');

                $text .= $list[$j+1];


            $list[$j+1] = "";
        }
        if($list[$j]=='"'){
                     //It is problematic one. When it works, if char is Ş or I it give ? 
                $text .= mb_strtoupper($list[$j+1],'UTF-8');

                $list[$j+1] = "";
        }
    }else{
        $text .= strtolower($list[$j]);
    }

}
$text .= " ";
}
```

**Error is below**

Expected : "Şike"
Shown : "?�ike"

Expected : "İstanbul"
Shown : "Istanbul"

Comment: Can you post a short, self-contained, reproducible example of your issue?

Comment: Of course, thank you for interesting.

I Edited my question you can see error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the above code? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I wrote my expectation for example : i expect "Şike" it doesn't return this.